# write pdf from dropbox to paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip, dropbox-api

I am attempting to copy pdf files from dropbox to paperclip.  Everything seems to work except that the pdf's fail to load when I try and view them from my rails application.

I have paperclip working:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :file, content_type: ["application/pdf", "application/x-pdf"]
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: ["application/pdf", "application/x-pdf", "application/rtf", 'application/x-rtf', 'text/rtf', 'text/plain']
end
```

To upload the file to paperclip I do the following:

```
contents = DropboxClient.new(DROPBOX_AUTH_TOKEN).get_file(PATH_TO_MY_PDF)
file = StringIO.new(contents)
file.class.class_eval{ attr_accessor :content_type, :original_filename }
file.content_type = "application/pdf"
file.original_filename = "my_pdf.pdf"
Document.create(file: file)
```

But when I click on a link that sends to a `send_data(@document.file, filename: @document.file_file_name)` the file is downloaded but cannot be opened. The downloaded file has content type of pdf and says it's 4kb where as the original is 10kb.

If it's helpful the contents that `DropboxClient.new(DROPBOX_AUTH_TOKEN).get_file(PATH_TO_MY_PDF)` returns is of the form

```
\x03Y\x8E\xCB\xC3\x97Zi\xA5\x92\xBB\xF1\xFD\xCD\x1D\xF5\x18\xF4\x95\xEB/\xD3\xAB\xCF\x9D\xB6\x02\x89\xDB\x9E\xE9\xBFJ!pF\xCB\xEA(\xC4B*\
```

but much longer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out everything was working fine.  But in using send data you need to send the raw data, not the paperclip file object (duh!).  Changing to

```
send_data(Paperclip.io_adapters.for(@document.file).read, filename: @document.file_file_name)
```

solved my problems.